# send sms through kannel using SMPPSim

Tags: ubuntu, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

I open the brearerbox, smsbox (bearerbox ./kannel.conf and smsbox ./kannel.conf) and the startsmppsim.sh file; and then when I open *http://localhost:15000/status* this is what is shown:

```
Kannel bearerbox version `1.4.5'. Build `Jul 28 2018 11:15:38', compiler `7.3.0'. System Linux, release 4.15.0-29-generic, version #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018, machine x86_64. Hostname shaghayegh-VirtualBox, IP 127.0.1.1. Libxml version 2.9.4. Using native malloc.

Status: running, uptime 0d 0h 9m 56s

WDP: received 0 (0 queued), sent 0 (0 queued)

SMS: received 0 (0 queued), sent 0 (0 queued), store size -1
SMS: inbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec, outbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec

DLR: received 0, sent 0
DLR: inbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec, outbound (0.00,0.00,0.00) msg/sec
DLR: 0 queued, using internal storage

Box connections:
    smsbox:(none), IP 127.0.0.1 (0 queued), (on-line 0d 0h 9m 45s)

SMSC connections:
    SMPPSim[SMPPSim]    SMPP:internal.smpp.ddj.co.za:2775/2775:smppclient1:smpp (re-connecting, rcvd: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), sent: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), failed 0, queued 0 msgs)
```

I can't exactly figure out what's is happening. I guess if everything is ok I should be able to send sms via this url: http://localhost:13015/cgi-bin/sendsms
but nothing happens.
I'm totally new to this subject and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

this my kannel.conf file

```
group = core
admin-port = 15000
smsbox-port = 15001
admin-password = bar
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group = smsc 
smsc = smpp 
smsc-id = SMPPSim
system-type = smpp 
service-type = smpp 
host = internal.smpp.ddj.co.za
port = 2775 
smsc-username = smppclient1 
smsc-password = password 
throughput=7 
transceiver-mode = true
send-url = http://localhost:13015/cgi-bin/sendsms 


group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
log-level = 0


group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No services defined"
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the port is one set on your config file "SMPPSim/conf/smppsim.props" line number 4 and the port is open using telnet,

```
telnet internal.smpp.ddj.co.za 2775
```

Also if SMPPSim is running on same server as kannel you can change host from "internal.smpp.ddj.co.za" to "127.0.0.1"